# LG Optimus Logic Transferring apps to Micro SD instead of internal memory

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sd-card, internal-storage, app2sd, lg-optimus-logic

I recently purchased an LG Optimus Logic Net10 phone which runs Android 2.3.6. The phone was advertised as having 1GB internal Memory and also came with a 4GB Micro SD.

When I download apps, they seem to not be using the memory properly. I tried to move apps to the SD Card, but the only option to move is "move to internal memory". "Move to SD" is not an option. When I select "move to internal memory" the apps go to the 1GB Internal Memory as I would expect. The option for memory management then changes to "Move to Phone".

I mounted a 32GB micro SD, so what I really want to do is move the apps from the 1 GB internal memory to the micro SD, but there is no option to do so. Is there a way to get the apps onto the SD card?

Thanks much!

Comment: Trouble is that the "standard App2SD" seems able only to switch between 2 storages. So as soon as there's an internal storage (as it is in your case), the sd card no longer is an option. I'm not sure whether one of the "extended App2SD apps" on the playstore can solve this, as I never used App2SD (I've got 6GB internal storage, so I never needed this) -- but it's certainly worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Go to app settings and click the apps that you want. When you click it, it should show its information and move to internal memory (aka MicroSD card).

Comment: In fact I'm doing this on my logic its a good phone i recommend

Answer (score 0):

The internal memory on a LG Logic is NOT the SD card.  There are 3 storages on the phone.  System storage, Internal storage 1 gb and the SD card that came with it.  4 gb.  Without software, you can't move any app to the SD card.